# Retrofit Android POST request with Header, Body, Path and Query

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit2

I need to do a Retrofit POST request by Android Kotlin code and the format is as:

```
[End Url]/api/customers/1/venues/55/abcfiles/sasfordownload?licenseid=01234567890&ispreproduction=true
```

Headers:

authorization -> Bearer someToken

Body:

{ "some_field" : {"55" : "29"}}

--

**Response:**

"Some String Value"

POST request:

```
@POST("customers/{customers}/venues/{venues}/abcfiles/sasfordownload")
fun makeRequestForfileUrl(
    @HeaderMap token: Map<String, String>,
    @Path("customers")
    customers: Int,
    @Path("venues")
    venues: Int,
    @Query("licenseid")
    licenceId: String,
    @Query("ispreproduction")
    ispreproduction: Boolean,
    @Body
    body: JSONObject
): Call<String>
```

Retrofit Builder:

```
fun requestApi(mContext: Context): ApiInterface {
return Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(apiUrl)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(
            OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(NetworkConnectionInterceptor(mContext))
                .addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor)
                .build()
        )
        .build()
        .create(ApiInterface::class.java)
}
```

Retrofit API request:

```
val headerMap = HashMap<String, String>()
    headerMap["Authorization"] = "Bearer $fetchedToken"
    headerMap["Content-Type"] = "application/json"

val apiInterface =
        ServiceGenerator.requestApi().makeRequestForfileUrl(
            headerMap,
            customerId,
            venueId,
            licenceId,
            true,
            JSONObject("{\"some_field\" : { \"55\" : \"29\" }}")
        )
```

Getting response code 500 for the above request.

**Response{protocol=h2, code=500, message=, url=[End Url]/api/customers/1/venues/55/abcfiles/sasfordownload?licenseid=0123456789&ispreproduction=true}**
Response body -> null

The API request is working on Postman.

Comment: Please share your Log, so that people can understand your issue properly.

Answer (score 0):

Working after Changing from `org.json.JSONObject` to `com.google.gson.JsonObject`

```
@POST("customers/{customers}/venues/{venues}/abcfiles/sasfordownload")
fun makeRequestForfileUrl(
@HeaderMap token: Map<String, String>,
@Path("customers")
customers: Int,
@Path("venues")
venues: Int,
@Query("licenseid")
licenceId: String,
@Query("ispreproduction")
ispreproduction: Boolean,
@Body
body: JsonObject //<- here changed org.json.JSONObject to com.google.gson.JsonObject
): Call<String>
```

And

```
val apiInterface =
    ServiceGenerator.requestApi().makeRequestForfileUrl(
        headerMap,
        customerId,
        venueId,
        licenceId,
        true,
        JsonObject) //<- "{\"some_field\" : { \"55\" : \"29\" }}" in this format 
    )
```

Don't know what is the difference between **org.json.JSONObject** and **com.google.gson.JsonObject**

But working with **com.google.gson.JsonObject**.

If anyone know the differences please add it here.